# Problems with npm versions of cordova project

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

I'm working on a Cordova Project.
In my project directory, if I type:

`node -v` I get `v6.11.1`

`npm -v` I get `3.10.10`

Sometimes, after adding a new plugin to the project (e.g `cordova-plugin-statusbar`), it happens that when I build the project I get this error:

```
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-statusbar" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-statusbar" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar@^2.2.3 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
...
...
npm ERR! Darwin 16.7.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.1/bin/node" "/Users/myuser/myprojectfolder/node_modules/.bin/npm" "install" "cordova-plugin-statusbar@^2.2.3"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
```

So npm version is different from the above one.

Can the problem of the plugin fetching be linked to this difference in the versions detected? 
And why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

`EPEERINVALID` means that some packages are outdated, you'll have to update global using `-g`:

> npm update -g

Else you could try re-installing `cordova` and `npm`:

> npm uninstall -g cordova
>
> npm uninstall
>
> npm install
>
> npm install -g cordova

Else if you use `nvm` as well? because if there's 2 different versions of `npm` it might be the case that you have to update `npm` while calling to the `nvm`.